# Details in the proof of irrationality of $\zeta(3)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

I am reading through Wadim Zudilin's lecture notes (https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1972uagq3zb4mc/AMiNT.pdf?dl=0 pages 75-76) and the author assumes some basic real/complex analysis facts without proofs which are the following (in question formats) :

1- Consider the function $g(y) = \Re f(z_0 + iy)$, that is, the real part of $f(z)$ on the contour of integration. How $\frac{d}{dy} g(y)=−\Im \frac{df}{dz}|_{z=z_0+iy}$ is true?

2- How the only $y$ for which $\Im\ln (y^{-2}-1)=0$ is $y=0$?

3- If $r_n^{1/n}$ tends to a positive quantity as $n\to\infty$, how do we conclude that $r_n$ does not vanish for all $n$ sufficiently large?

4- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n^{1/n}|\lt1$ then how do we know that $|a_n|<1$ for all $n$ suitably large?

Comment: The point (1) is one of the Cauchy-Riemann equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Comment: @zinoviev one derivative is w.r.t $z$

Comment: Point (2) follows from the definition of complex log: $ln(z) = \operatorname{Ln}(z) + i\theta$ depending on the branch cut that you choose. Hence $\Im ln(z) = \theta$. If $y=0$ the argument is zero.

Comment: For point (3), use the identity $0^{1/n}=0$. So if $r_n=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$ it follows that $r_n^{1/n}=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and therefore $r_n^{1/n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @zinoviev could you read my reply and edit for point 1?

Comment: @TheMagicMountain yes, I updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the point (1):

Under the assumptions of the theorem for the Cauchy-Riemann equations if $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ and $\frac{df}{dz}\Big|_{z=z_{0}+iy}$ exists, then

$$ \frac{df}{dz} \Big|_{z=z_{0}+iy} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} -i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

Now if $$\displaystyle g(y) = \Re f(z_{0}+iy) = u(z_{0},y) $$

then $$ \frac{dg(y)}{dy} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} $$

On the other hand

$$\Im \frac{df}{dz} \Big|_{z=z_{0}+iy} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{dg(y)}{dy} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \Im \frac{df}{dz} \Big|_{z=z_{0}+iy} $$

In the book $z_{0}$ is assumed $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

For the point (2):

You have a typo, in the book the author put $\ln(z^{-2}-1)$

Suppose $z = x+iy$

Then

$$z^{-2}-1 = -\frac{(x+iy)^2-1}{(x+iy)^2} = -\frac{\left[(x+iy)^2-1\right](x-iy)^2}{(x+iy)^2(x-iy)^2} = \frac{-y^4-2x^2y^2+x^2-y^2-y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2} - i\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2 }$$
Hence

$$\Im (z^{-2}-1)  = -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2 }$$

$ \Longrightarrow \theta = \operatorname{Arg}(z^{-2}-1) = \Im \ln(z^{-2}-1)=0 $ if

$$ -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} =0$$

which only happens when $y=0$ given that in the book $x\neq 0$

For the point (4):

This is the ratio test for series:

Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists and is strictly less than $1$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges absolutely.

Then as a part of the Cauchy criterion we can show that if

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \;\textrm{ converges then } \;  a_{n} \to 0$$

Then $\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that
$$|a_{n}-0|<\epsilon$$

Choose $\epsilon =1$

Comment: Sorry  @Alann Rosas, it was a typo, the explanation was for point (4).

Comment: In point 2, the numerator will be x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 - x^2 + 2 i x y + y^4 + y^2

Comment: @TheMagicMountain I corrected that part, thanks